Why are there selection rules in electronic transitions?
Why are there selection rules in electronic transitions? What restricts electrons from making transitions to certain states although it is energetically possible?

Are you aware of Fermi’s Golden Rule?

I am unsure of what type of answer and the level of answer you are looking for. If you are looking for a mathematical answer, it is because of the symmetries of functions, and the symmetry of the functions is determined by the quantum numbers.
Let's use dipole transitions to be concrete. An electric dipole transition requires a vector operator $\boldsymbol{\hat{r}}$. The probability of a transition from state 2 to state 1 is proportional to
\begin{equation}
\int \Psi_2 \boldsymbol{\hat{r}}\Psi_1 \mathrm{d}V
\end{equation}
Let's say the result of the operator acting on $\Psi_1$ is some other function $F$. When the functions $\Psi_2$ and $F$ are orthogonal, the integral will evaluate to zero. This would then be a forbidden transition. If it is non-zero, it would be an allowed transition.
